# Can apache rewrite rules go in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

How do I create a simple apache rewrite rule to rewrite:

http://domain.com/vanity to http://domain.com/foo/

Also can rewrite rules go in httpd.conf or do they have to go in a .htaccess file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your website's `<virtualhost>`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/vanity$ /foo/ [L]
```

The `[L]` will silently redirect, so the user will still see /vanity in the URL. You could use `[R]` to force a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

They go in **httpd.conf**.  Check out the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

For httpd.conf, wrap 'Directory' tags around your rewrite rules.
For .htaccess there's no need. 
It's generally considered more secure to put them in your httpd.conf however, so this is what I do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact apache [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) recommend `httpd` instead of `.htaccess`

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
> to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down
> your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a
> .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the
> same effect with better performance.

`httpd.conf` perform better but your `.htaccess` file will look different from `httpd` because variables in httpd might have full paths.