# Get the same result without using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Root directory:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

/data directory

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error
Options -Indexes
```

How can I get the same result without using htaccess, **by editing the apache config file?**

Comment: I don't understand whats your question.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir: sorry, now it should be more clear

Comment: You can put your rules into virtualhost of your website. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941879/can-apache-rewrite-rules-go-in-httpd-conf